# F# - Custom max function over Operators.max - Huge performance hit

Tags: .net, f#

I implemented a sequential version of the LCS algorithm in F#, and ran it against two strings of 100,000 characters each. It consistently took around 490 seconds to run to completion. I expected something closer to 70 seconds.

After a lot of troubleshooting, I tracked this down to my use of a custom max function - removing that reduced the run time to 42 seconds.

Can anyone tell me why using a custom max function has such a massive performance hit? In this instance it was 12x slower to use a custom max function over <strike>System.Math.Max</strike> Operators.max!

This is the function I was using:

```
let max (a:int) (b:int) : int = if a > b then a else b
```

Comment: Try adding `inline`.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks! That answers my question.

Comment: Why don't you use the operator 'max'? [Operators.max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353702.aspx) [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qbk4l4)

Comment: @ildjarn: Why doesn't F# inline a function like this itself?

Comment: @FoggyFinder looks like I was mistaken as to which max function F# uses by default. Thanks for pointing this out. Now that I think about it, its pretty obvious given "max" vs "Max"! Operators.max is the one I switched to prior to asking the question, rather than Math.Max.

Comment: I think this is essentially the same question as the one above - which has a couple of answers with more detailed explanations on how F# comparison is compiled.

Comment: @TomasPetricek in this case the function is not generic though. Does inline change the performance characteristic of comparison even though the function is restricted to int? If so why? Thx.

Comment: @s952163 : Because it is still inlined, avoiding the overhead of a function call...

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thanks Tomas - that is indeed a helpful answer.

Comment: @SimonShine : That would be a very complex criteria to define...

Comment: @ildjarm: Are you saying it would be complex to define when it is possible or when it leads to an improvement?

Comment: @SimonShine : Both what constitutes an improvement, and when the implied possible change in semantics is actually desired. Both seem quite subjective to me.

Comment: @ildjarn: What change of semantics occurs when inlining functions? I was thinking of improvements in running time, as inlining necessarily takes up more space. Since the effects of inlining on instruction caches is non-trivial, I'm not proposing that writing inlining heuristics is obvious.

Comment: @SimonShine : Stack traces are lost for exceptions, type inference works differently (esp. for numeric types).